# hibernate tables are not generated in play framework production mode

Tags: hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am developing an application with play framework, mySQL and using Hibernate for ORM. When I run the application in development mode tables are created for each entity, but when I tried to run it in production mode I am getting an exception.

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not
>   mapped

exception. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after adding

> PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false

to build.sbt file.